# How to get Netherlands neighborhood names based on Addresses?

Tags: geolocation, address, postal-code, europe, netherlands

CBS provides [key figures on the neighborhood level](https://opendata.cbs.nl/statline/?dl=29707#/CBS/nl/dataset/84799NED/table?ts=1603899036287) for the whole country(NL). I want to incorporate this data for analysis but my datapoints include addresses and postcodes and latitudes&longitudes, not neighborhood names. Is there an easy way to match each address to the corresponding neighborhood?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a downloadable pdok gis dataset for CBS "wijken en buurten"
https://www.pdok.nl/introductie/-/article/cbs-wijken-en-buurten
You can then perform a spatial join between your latlong data and the wijken-en-buurten layer, to connect the neighborhoud name to your locations.

Comment: I think this is a sufficient answer. I have no GIS know-how though. Could you also point me to the documentation of the resources needed to parse the weird xml files my browser opens instead of downloading something? My end goal is to add a new column(neighborhood CBS name) to a pandas df containing the lat/longs as columns. I could also do it in an SQL table or in a CSV format table.

Comment: In the ATOM xml the following zip download fle is shown: http://geodata.nationaalgeoregister.nl/wijkenbuurten2019/extract/wijkenbuurten2019.zip